# How can I make my android turn the screen on and unlock when I touch the screen?

Tags: applications, security, settings, lock-screens, screen

I want to mount an android tablet on the wall, and want it to turn the screen off when not in use, but turn back on whenever you tap the screen (similar to waking up a computer while jiggling the mouse). Is there any way to accomplish this?

Comment: On some devices there is an option to "wake up on double tap the screen". I have seen this on multiple Lenovo devices. Not sure if other manufacturer have similar options.

Comment: Turning the screen on when touched would require kernel level support. The workaround would be to check if your device supports turning the screen brightness to 0 (or so dim that you can accept it just as dark) nits. Try some apps from Play Store to see which app is successful in fully turning down the brightness. The first part, turning the screen off when not in use can be done using an automation app. Try  with Automate (Llama), MacroDroid or Tasker automation app.